# Why resize event doesn't fire when scrollbar appears or disappears?

Tags: javascript, browser

When browser's vertical scrollbar appears or disappears, the width of viewport or browser window changes (can be tested using jQuery's $(window).width() method), but window's resize event is not triggered. How come?

Answer (score 2):

Re-size is an event that is driven by the actual browser window changing size.

What if I removed elements from my page until my content fit within the screen ? That's not a window re-size. Or if i change the overflow for the page to hidden. The scroll bars will disappear, however this again is not a re size.

What I am getting at is this: Scrollbar visibility does not necessarily mean that there was a re-size event.

Comment: If it's not a window resize, then why jQuery returns a different width for window?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resize, use overflowchanged event.

Comment: overflowchanged is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Browsers don't recognize it as resize. Then if you need "scrollbar appeared" and "scrollbar disappeared" events, use this code:

```
<div id="footerDiv" style="float: left; height: 1px; width: 100%;"></div>



bodywidth = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    bodywidth = $("#footerDiv").width();
    setInterval(scrollbarHelper, 100);

});

function scrollbarHelper() { 

    var newwidth = $("#footerDiv").width();

    if (bodywidth !== newwidth) {

        if (bodywidth > newwidth) {
            alert("Scrollbar Appeared");
            // Your code here
        }
        else if (bodywidth < newwidth) {
            alert("Scrollbar Disppeared");
            // Your code here
        }

        bodywidth = newwidth;
    }
}
```